# sound track pro

Tags: track, post-production

how to import wav files into the tracks

Answer (score 1):

select your file through the browser window in the bottom right of your screen.
double click to open into a single file project or click and drag into the timeline to import the WAV into your mix.
hope that's what you were after

Comment: not to be pedantic, but double clicking in STP is a bane. I wished they had spent more time building the UI.

Answer (score 0):

What program are you using? Do you mean, import a track into a program or ..import several tracks with a specific time code into a program?